# Resonant Frequency & Opera Singers

Tags: string-theory, waves, acoustics, resonance, string

Would it be possible under math of strings to note the frequency of each string vibrations? And in doing so, in hand with using the technique opera singers use to shatter glass with their voice, would it be possible to destroy/aggravate each string accordingly?

Comment: Are you asking whether opera singers can bring strings as in *guitar strings* to resonate with them, or are you, as the tag suggests, under the impression that *string theory* has something to do with objects physically vibrating?

Comment: As the tag suggest...

Comment: You keep using that tag, string-theory. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I agree that first sentence is a mess,but the second sentence was very clear to me ,I understood it immediately.Its in my opinion good and clear question.I would personaly not close this.OP is asking if the strings have resonance like guitar strings for example,and if it is possible to destroy them via excitation by unspecified force of frequency equal to resonance of the string.He used the opera singer - glass as analogy,he is not asking if you can resonate strings to destruction by sound of human voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article on String theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Testability_and_experimental_predictions),

> At sufficiently high energies, the string-like nature of particles would become obvious. There should be heavier copies of all particles, corresponding to higher vibrational harmonics of the string. It is not clear how high these energies are. In most conventional string models, they would be close to the Planck energy, which is $10^{14}$ times higher than the energies accessible in the newest particle accelerator, the LHC, making this prediction impossible to test with any particle accelerator in the near future.

The maximum energy of the LHC is about 7 TeV, so the vibrations of the strings would be around 7000 YeV ([yotta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotta-)-electron-volts).

We, as a race, cannot produce the energy required to *access* these energies even mechanically, so it would be quite impossible for a *single human* to access (and subsequently destroy) a string with their voice alone.